# Settings.System.canWrite always returns false

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, system-setting

I use below code for getting system permission...what happening even if permission is allowed; still it's showing..

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !Settings.System.canWrite(ChooseSender_Receiver.this)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + ChooseSender_Receiver.this.getPackageName()));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS);
        }
```

**Note:** My problem is even if permission is already allows still it's showing popup..when deny and allows the permission dialog is dismissing.

My device is Moto e2 & Redmi mbls version **M**

[image]

Comment: Well is this a Device specific problem ? I have just tested it on Android O emulator  . And its working fine . Try to test it on several other devices. And let us know the Device info .

Comment: @ADM thank you sir.. it's working from 7.0 version..I have from below 7.0 as  I Mention **My problem is even if permission is already allows still it's showing popup..when deny and allows the permission dialog is dismissing**

Comment: Starange . I have just tested it Lenovo device which is running on Android M . And its working as expected. You should add the device info with OS version to question.

Comment: @ADM my device is **Moto e2** sir.....i will list some device which is not working properly...

Comment: @ADM sir can you killed the app and restart the application in this case you will get again permission..can you check same device Lenovo

Comment: Already did . I also clear data of the app and even after clear data permission is there Granted.

Comment: @ADM ya its ok sir....problem is that permission is Granted even why i am getting popup likr can modify system setting permission page.

Comment: Thats the problem at your end when i tested i did not faced it . So you better all devices list in your question with details . maybe Someone will look into it having same device . Chances are good huh ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally  there  is no solution for this**

> Its based on device hardware issues..i check share it application even it's
>   asking two time permission.